# Query a related entity by id in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, odata

I use the c# web api in combination with the entity framework. The http requests are generated by the sap ui5 framework. The generated get request looks like:
"http://localhost:52854/KddietzTourenplan/5/KddietzTour/1"
How must the name of the associated method and parameters?

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<KddietzTour> GetKddietzTour([FromODataUri] int key, ???)
    {
        return _oContext.KddietzTour.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.NTourenplanId == key);
    }
```

I know, the simplest request would be "http://localhost:52854/KddietzTour/1". But as mentioned before, the requests are generated from another framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HttpGet Attribute to map the URL to the method and its parameters. to map the parameters you need to use `{ParameterName}` inside the template you're using in HttpGet

```
[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet("KddietzTourenplan/5/KddietzTour/{key}")]
public IQueryable<KddietzTour> GetKddietzTour([FromODataUri] int key, ???)
{
    return _oContext.KddietzTour.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.NTourenplanId == key);
}
```